How could I fit a model of a non-homogeneous Poisson process in STAN?
I have some data $t_1, t_2, ..., t_n$ where $0 < t_i < T$ for all $t_i$.
I assume that this has been generated by an inhomogeneous Poisson process with parameter $\lambda(t)$ defined again for $0 < t < T$. I further assume that this has some fixed form, consider for simplicity:
$\lambda(t) = \exp(\theta_1 + \theta_2t)$. I know how to solve this particular case, but eventually, I would like to be able to get a more complicated formula than this and be able to easily try different variants.
How could I code this in STAN or similar software declaratively to obtain the parameters $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$ estimates (MLE) from $t_i$?
